# ng-submit using factory function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

I have factory with function setRoot() like below and want to use it in controller

```
$scope.testSubmit = testFactory.setRoot();
```

but when open html where there is ng-submit="testSubmit()" I just get factory function executed before even typing anything into input;) So how I can use factory function in my ng-submit ?

```
.factory('testFactory', function($rootScope){
        return {           
            setRoot: function(){
                $rootScope.root = 'inside testFactory';
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call your function right away, so do it like this instead:

```
$scope.testFactory = testFactory;
```

And in your `ng-submit` do:

```
ng-submit="testFactory.setRoot()"
```

This will first bind the factory to the `$scope` which makes it possible for you to access its functions, in this case `.setRoot`, which you only want to call in the actual `ng-submit`. Not when binding the factory to the `$scope`.

You should be aware of this but as soon as you put `()` after a function it means you execute it. If you simply want to bind a certain function but call it later you can just do `$scope.testFactory = testFactory.setRoot` and then use `ng-submit="testFactory()"` directly.

The biggest issue with your function though is that you're trying to set `$rootScope` from inside a factory, which will not work. You cannot set `$scope` from inside a factory either. So you will have to return a value which you then bind to either `$rootScope` or `$scope` in your controller.

Comment: thnx , appreciate. Now factory function setRoot()  doesn't execute on page load, but when I click submit it doesn't change $rootScope.root too ? trying to put it here http://jsfiddle.net/2oeskzhL/

Comment: @irom Not entirely sure what you mean but using $scope in a child scope will never affect the parent scope, nor $rootScope.

Comment: hm.. so how do I change something in root scope using factory function ?

Comment: @irom You want to avoid cluttering the $rootScope if you can, but if you want to use $rootScope instead just inject it into your controller like you do with the $scope, and then just bind to the $rootScope instead of $scope.

Comment: @irom You can't set $rootScope or $scope from inside a factory. So your function will not work.

Comment: so what's the best practice here, how I can set something in parent scope using factory function ?

Comment: @irom Simply return the value you want to bind from the factory function and then use $parent.$scope to bind to the parent scope, instead of cluttering the $rootScope.